# How to choose gpu among multiple nvidia gpu in ffmpeg 3.2.0?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, nvenc

i'm currently using two nvidia p4 graphic cards.

In previous version of ffmpeg(before 3.2.0), i could choose specific gpu card by using options "-gpu 0 or 1 etc".

In current version, however, there's no option for selecting gpu card.

Actually there's "gpu" option specified in nvenc_h264.c or nvenc_hevc.c.

But in nvenc.c file, there's no code that uses "gpu" option.

Is there any way that i can choose specific card?

How load balancing between two cards is done?

Is it done in driver level?

Thank you.

Comment: Show the full ffmpeg command you tried and its console output.

Comment: it goes like below

```ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -gpu 2 -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -vf scale_npp=1280:720 -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu 0 output.mp4```

For any number after "-gpu", it works. it's problem. if i indicate gpu which is not exist, it shouldn't be working.

Comment: I'm not clear. So the GPU selection works if the index is valid but not otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

I have this same issue. When transcoding, no matter which gpu I select with `-gpu` 
option, ffmpeg always use gpu #0.

I managed to solve it by use `-hwaccel_device #` instead of `-gpu`

For example:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i <input> -b:v 2048k -vf scale_npp=1280:-1 -c:v h264_nvenc -y <output>
```

Answer (score 0):

If automatic load balancing is good enough for you, you can do the following

```
    if (ctx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264){
         av_opt_set(ctx->priv_data, "gpu", "any", 0);
     }
```

-gpu any/list

Also in case you are looking for command line take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424350/how-to-specify-the-gpu-to-be-used-by-nvenc-in-ffmpeg) post

Comment: That post was removed. I suppose we'll never know the command line.